# powershell cannot index into a null array during simple array operation

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and run into problems. I try to make a powershell script that reads in a txt file which depicts the location of a chess, by using the format "x,y,b", where x and y are the planar coordinates of a chess with color b.

I wrote the following code in ps:

```
function makeboard2d($file){
    $blankline=-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1
  $board2d=$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline,$blankline
    $board=Get-Content $file
    
    for ($i=0;$i -le $board.Length;$i++){
     
        $x=$board[$i][0]
        $y=$board[$i][2]
        $b=$board[$i][4]
        
        $board2d[$x][$y]=$b
    }
    
}
makeboard2d("G:\board.txt")
```

and the txt file G:\board.txt has the following content, in format "x,y,b":

```
1,2,1
3,3,0
```

What I am trying to do first is to construct a blank 15-by-15 chessboard($board2d) having each entry set to -1, meaning that no chess has been placed upon. Then I need to read in lines of input(e.g. 1,2,1) from G:\board.txt, i.e. alternating moves from players A and B, and use such column of inputs to modify the aforementioned two-dimensional board, $board2d. Here error occurs from $x=$board[$i][0] inside the loop.

Could you be so kind as to offer some guidance?

Thank you indeed.

Comment: `Get-Content $file` returns a (one dimensional) list of strings. You will need to convert each string in a subarray. Something like: `($board[$i].split(','))[0]`

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep all your kind opinions by heart.

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems here.

1. if you create your board2d as is, it will change all element from a same column (if col 2 is setted, col 2 will be setted for all rows )
2. `$x, $y, $b` are defined from a character (0, 2 and 4). 2 problems with this, first your board is 15x15, so for col/row 11 and beyond it needs 2 characters. Second, if you use character, `$x, $y, $b` are setted with ascii value for this character and not the actual value
3. your loop goes too far `-lt` is needed

   ```
    function makeboard2d($file){
       $board2d = @()
       for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt 15; $i++)
       {
          $board2d += , @(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
       }
       $board=Get-Content $file

       for ($i=0;$i -lt $board.Length;$i++){
          $values = $board[$i] -split ','
          $x=$values[0]     # Index here is for an array value, not a character
          $y=$values[1]
          $b=$values[2]
          $board2d[$x][$y]=$b
       }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-Content` cmdlet reads in the file as a 1-dimensional array of **strings**.
If you want this to become a multidimensional array, you could do

```
# initialize board to an array of arrays with all -1 values:
$board2d = for ($i = 0; $i -lt 15; $i++) { ,@(-1,-1,-1) }

# set board to whatever is in the file
$file = 'D:\Test\board.txt'
$board2d = Get-Content -Path $file
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $board2d.Count; $i++) { $board2d[$i] = ($board2d[$i] -split ',') }
```

The array values will all be of type string. If you need them to be numbers for calculation purposes, do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $board2d.Count; $i++) { $board2d[$i] = [int[]]($board2d[$i] -split ',') }
```

Reference the different values by Index (indices start at 0)

```
# $board2d[0][0]  --> first element in the array, X value
# $board2d[0][1]  --> first element in the array, Y value
# $board2d[0][2]  --> first element in the array, Color value
# $board2d[1][0]  --> second element in the array, X value
# $board2d[1][1]  --> second element in the array, Y value
# $board2d[1][2]  --> second element in the array, Color value
```

However, it may be much more comfortable to use an array of **objects** with named properties:

```
# initialize board to an array of objects with all properties set to -1:
$board2d = for ($i = 0; $i -lt 15; $i++) { [PsCustomObject]@{X = -1; Y = -1; Color = -1} }

# set board to whatever is in the file
$file = 'D:\Test\board.txt'
$board2d = Import-Csv -Path $file -Header X,Y,Color
```

Here again, all values read from the file are of type string. To convert to integer numbers you can do:

```
$board2d = Import-Csv -Path $file -Header X,Y,Color | 
           Select-Object @{Name = 'X'; Expression = { [int]$_.X}},
                         @{Name = 'Y'; Expression = { [int]$_.Y}},
                         @{Name = 'Color'; Expression = { [int]$_.Color}}
```

Now you can reference the different values by property Name

```
# $board2d[0].X      --> first element in the array, X value
# $board2d[0].Y      --> first element in the array, Y value
# $board2d[0].Color  --> first element in the array, Color value
# $board2d[1].X      --> second element in the array, X value
# $board2d[1].Y      --> second element in the array, Y value
# $board2d[1].Color  --> second element in the array, Color value
```